# Salesforce Parse Json to account Object

Tags: json, rest

JSON Sample:

```json
{
  "metaAcc": {
    "totalRecords": "234",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "pageSize": "200",
    "lastPage": true
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "AccountDetails",
      "id": "333333",
      "attributes": {
        "fieldcode1": "20015300",
        "fieldDescription": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "AccountDetails",
      "id": "4444",
      "attributes": {
        "fieldcode1": "20016080",
        "fieldDescription": "test"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to get the value of fieldcode1 . Kindly help . I have created the JSON2Apex class and using in the class

Comment: sorry typo !!!! I am not able to get the value of fieldcode1 . Kindly help . I have created the JSON2Apex class and using in the class

Comment: Can you include your JSON2Apex class and tell us more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a class that represent such data structures you could utilize [typed deserialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize):
`JSON2Apex accountInfo = (JSON2Apex) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, JSON2Apex.class);`

At this point you just have to loop on `data` property, then access to `attributes` one and you can get the value of `fieldcode1`.
This for-loop should do the trick:

```
for (JSON2Apex.Data d : accountInfo.data) {
    System.debug('Id: ' + d.id + ' - fieldcode1: ' + d.attributes.fieldcode1);
}
```

By the way, JSON2Apex tool map the json `type` attribute to a `type_Z` class property.
You could modify  a bit the generated class in order to have a 1:1 mapping:

```
public class JSON2Apex {
    public MetaAcc metaAcc;
    public List<Data> data;

    public class MetaAcc {
        public String totalRecords;
        public String pageNumber;
        public String pageSize;
        public Boolean lastPage;
    }
    
    public class Attributes {
        public String fieldcode1;
        public String fieldDescription;
    }
    
    public class Data {
        public String type;
        public String id;
        public Attributes attributes;
    }
}
```

You could test it with this anonymous script:

```
// your json
String jsonString = '{"metaAcc": { "totalRecords": "234", "pageNumber": "1", "pageSize": "200", "lastPage": true }, "data": [ { "type": "AccountDetails", "id": "333333", "attributes": { "fieldcode1": "20015300", "fieldDescription": "test" } }, { "type": "AccountDetails", "id": "4444", "attributes": { "fieldcode1": "20016080", "fieldDescription": "test" }}]}';
// typed deserialization
JSON2Apex accountInfo = (JSON2Apex) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, JSON2Apex.class);
// loop on data list
for (JSON2Apex.Data d : accountInfo.data) {
    System.debug('Id: ' + d.id + ' - fieldcode1: ' + d.attributes.fieldcode1);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruben , Great !! it worked well .. Thank you so much for your kind help. Really Appreciate it !!! :)